# JavaFX 11 Unicode characters sequence get inversed

Tags: java, javafx, unicode, rendering, javafx-11

Some of the Unicode characters are **inversely** rendered in JavaFX 11.

- Language: [Tai Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_languages)
- Font: Pyidaungsu. Click this [Link](http://unicode.today/fonts/Pyidaungsu-2.5_Regular.ttf) to download
- Text to render: **ၸေႃႇၵျီႇ**
- OS: Windows 10
- Program code guide: [Getting started with JavaFx 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)
- Program code:

  ```
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
      String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
      String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
      Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
      l.setFont(new Font("Pyidaungsu", 20));

      String problemString = "ၸေႃႇၵျီႇ";
      String fixedString = Normalizer.normalize(problemString, Normalizer.Form.NFC);

      Label l2 = new Label(fixedString);
      l2.setFont(new Font("Pyidaungsu", 30));
      Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(l, l2), 640, 480);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
  }
  ```
- Compiling command : `javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX%
  --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HelloFX.java -encoding UTF-8`
- Result:

[image: Result of running]

**The first two characters are rendered inversely.** The situation is the same in JavaFX 8.

Comment: That must be a text render bug for this script. Nothing you can do about it, except filing a bug report to Oracle.

Comment: Clicking your link to the font _Pyidaungsu_ triggers an immediate download! That's not good. Please modify your question so that clicking the link sends the reader to a page where they can **choose whether to do a download or not**. Alternatively, change the text to something like _"Font: Pyidaungsu. Click [this link](http://unicode.today/fonts/Pyidaungsu-2.5_Regular.ttf) to download it."_ so that the reader will not accidentally perform an unwanted download.

Comment: [1] If I copy your `problemString` declaration, and paste it into a NetBeans edit window, it also reverses the first two characters (`ေ` and `ၸ`), even if the display font is _Pyidaungsu_ It also does the same thing when using other valid fonts such  as _Myanmar Text_. I don't have any problems when pasting into Intellij IDEA, Eclipse or STS. Were you using NetBeans to test this? [2] The browser won't allow me to select only the first character of `problemString`; the smallest unit I can select is "`ၸေ`". I don't know anything about Thai, but is that possibly relevant?

Comment: Maybe the two IDEs use different engine?